# Showing mathjax equation one by one

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I want to do following:

1. Make all formulas on page invisible.
2. Typeset all equations. As soon equation is ready, make it visible.

First is very easy to do with jQuery. `$(".formula").css("visibility","hidden")`.

I don't know how to do second.

If I write MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]) then it will load all formulas and then fires callback.

How can this be done one by one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems working, but solution is not elegant.

```
typesetMath(jQuery(".formula"),0);


function typesetMath(formulas,ind){
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,formulas.get(ind)], 
          function(){
              jQuery(formulas.get(ind)).css("visibility","visible");
              if(ind+1<formulas.length)
                   typesetMath(formulas,ind+1);
         });
}
```